# What is the name of this?

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, diesel, jetta

[image]

My car is hard to shift gears and found out this was the reason. Any idea what’s the name of this part?

Comment: What is the make/model/year of the vehicle? Not only could we probably get you a name, we could probably get you a part number as well.

Comment: This is for a vw Jetta 2005 tdi 1.9L (manual transmission)

Comment: It's a gear selection cable end which is apparently broken: it should have sort of "claws" that catch on cable threads.

Comment: Egad, that's a terrible hack. You need to replace that linkage, big-time!

Comment: @max you should go ahead and answer the question for real!

Comment: There's a second cable that deal with the other axis (one is the fore/aft motion of the lever, the other side-to-side) that is visible to the right of the pic. It should look like that.

Answer (score 2):

Those are shift cables, there are 2. I suggest replacing both.

[image]

.
[image]

.

[image]